# Does std::vector have a copy constructor for references?

Tags: c++, reference

I was surprised when I saw code like this and it worked:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
    std::vector<int> subvec = vec.back();
    vec.pop_back();
    for (int i : subvec) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I was wondering about the line `std::vector<int> subvec = vec.back();` followed by `vec.pop_back();`. At first I was expecting it to fail. `vec.back()` returns a reference to an element which is destroyed on the next line. Then I thought it's calling the copy constructor of `std::vector`. But if `vec.back()` is returning a reference, does that mean that `std::vector` has a seperate copy constructor for pointers? When I tried to build an example with my own classes, this was the only way I was able to replicate the behavior.

Comment: Look up copy initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `std::vector<int> subvec = vec.back();`, `subvec` is copied from `vec.back()`. Even `vec.back()` returns-by-reference, `subvec` is a brand-new object and has nothing to with the original `vector` (`vec.back()`); `vec.pop_back();` won't affect it at all.

On the other hand, if you declare `subvec` as reference, then

```
std::vector<int>& subvec = vec.back(); // subvec refers to vec.back() too
vec.pop_back();                        // subvec becomes dangled
for (int i : subvec) {                 // UB
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

> But if `vec.back()` is returning a reference, does that mean that `std::vector` has a seperate copy constructor for pointers?

No. For `std::vector<int> subvec = vec.back();`, the copy constructor taking `const std::vector<int>&` is used to initialize `subvec`. There's no such thing like copy constructor *for reference*, in overload resolution the referenced object other than the reference itself will be considered; [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) is just alias. (And there's no copy construtor taking pointers either for other reason, if there's a constructor taking pointers it won't be copy constructor again.)

> Declares a named variable as a reference, that is, an alias to an already-existing object or function.

Comment: I get that. But to realize this behavior, does std::vector have an overloaded copy constructor for references?

Comment: @Picard Answer revised.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking about a copy constructor for pointers, because I thought of the reference as a pointer. but it's clearer when I think about the reference as an alias, rather than a memory address.

Comment: @Picard references are aliases to other objects, not objects in their own right. The normal copy constructor applies.

Comment: @Picard Yes, references and pointers are different things in concept. And yes you can just think reference as alias, it's quite helpful.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact the `&`operator is used for getting the address as well as declaring a reference.

Comment: @Picard The `&` in [address of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) and `&` in reference declaration are two unrelated things, it's better to think of them separately.

Answer (score 3):

`vec` is a vector of `std::vector<int>`'s. The initialization of `subvec`:

```
std::vector<int> subvec = vec.back();
```

copies the last `std::vector<int>` element into `subvec`. You are not storing a reference to the `vec`'s back in `subvec`, but a copy. These are independent.

---

The [constructor overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) involved in the initialization of `subvec` is:

```
vector(const vector& other);
```

The `back()` member function returns an *lvalue reference*, which can be bound to the `const` lvalue reference the constructor above takes. Therefore, there is no need for an additional constructor overload for lvalue references.